# please tell me where i went wrong in writing code to download a image from internet

Tags: python-3.x

I want to download an image from the internet and wrote a code it isn't working 
want to know where I went wrong

```
import random
import urllib.request
 def web_image (url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name)+"jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,full_name)

web_image("https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose- blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=format%2Ccompress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500")
```

Comment: *what* about it isn't working? Give us an error message, or be more specific about what you're expecting vs what you're getting, so we can understand what's actually going wrong.

Comment: your url is down, change your url then try and if you face an error, tell us what you get.

Comment: yaa! it is working if i changed the url         when there is no http in url it is working                 but why